# Will a 5200mAh 30C 22.2V 6S Lipo battery work with

Tags: quadcopter

I am building a Quadcopter and I was wondering if a 5200mAh 30C 22.2V 6S Lipo battery will work with a 40Amp Esc's, MT4108 370 KV Motors, and GEMFAN 1470 Carbon Fiber Props. The over all payload will be about 5-6 pounds.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Ben, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your motors are rated for 466W max, which with a 6S battery gives about 20A max current draw per motor (This also tells you your ESC are a good choice, provided that they can handle the 6S voltage).

I'd estimate the hover voltage at about 10A, so you'd get a flight duration of t = Capacity(C) / Current(I) = 5.2/40 = 0.13h = 7.8mins.

This flight duration sounds a bit small. I'd try something that would get me to 10+minutes, depending on application.

**That said, the correct way to approach this**, would be to get some real data from your power system, either experimentally or online. The course of action is:

(1) Set a bench test with one propeller and motor fixed on a thrust bench or scale.

(2) Run your motor to the maximum and record the current $I_{max}$. This will verify the motor and ESC maximum specs.

(3) Run your motor to produce thrust equal to 1/4 of the estimated quadrotor weight. This will give you your hover current, $I_H$.
(4) Use $I_H$ and your required flight time to calculate the required battery capacity.